# huffman decoding from a given file

Tags: java, binary-tree, huffman-code

I am given a string of characters that I have to encode and decode using the ideas of the huffman tree. The original string of characters is uploaded as a file, and the return for the encode method is a new file containing the translation table and the encoded message, in order.

Here is an example of what an output file would contain.

{0=0100, 1=0111, 2=11, 3=00, 4=10, 5=0110,
=0101}

0110101100111101110100011100111000100011001011100101

My encode method:

```
 Map<Character, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>(); //store char, freq in map
        for (char c: message.toCharArray()) { //thank you enhanced for loop
            freq.put(c, freq.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
        }

        //queue stores nodes
        PriorityQueue<Node> pq;
        pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(l -> l.freq)); 
        //nodes will be sorted by comparator

        //using hashmap we add the nodes to the queue
        for (var entry : freq.entrySet()) {
            pq.add(new Node(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }

        while (pq.size() != 1) //must be more than 1 node
        {
            //removes the two nodes of lowest freq
            Node left = pq.poll();
            Node right = pq.poll();

            //connect new nodes
            int sum = left.freq + right.freq; //summary of freq, for parent
            pq.add(new Node('\0', sum, left, right)); //add back
        }

        //root of tree
        Node root = pq.peek();

        //new map for huffman codes
        Map<Character, String> huffmanCode = new HashMap<>();
        coding(root, "", huffmanCode);
        

        //testing
        //print the Huffman codes so we can know them (move this later)
        //System.out.println("Huffman code is " + huffmanCode);

        //testing
        //print encoded message
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c: message.toCharArray()) {
            sb.append(huffmanCode.get(c));
        }
        //System.out.println("Encoded string is : " + sb); //check file format

         Pair<Map,StringBuilder> p = new Pair<Map,StringBuilder>(huffmanCode,sb);
        
        return p;
```

I convert the pair into a string in the main method.

In order to decode this string, I am supposed to re-upload the file and use the information it contains to create a new file with the original uncoded message. I would have no problem decoding the message if it weren't for the uploading requirement. I lose access to the huffman tree I previously encoded and I have been unable to preserve it in the output files as I am required to only return strings.

I have tried splitting strings and working backwards from the table, but without the tree I am really struggling to decode the string without the huffman tree. Is there any way to preserve the tree in the output file, or is there a way to reconstruct the tree using the translation table? Thanks.

Comment: What makes you say you are losing access to the tree? Split up your method into smaller methods, and have one of them return the tree. Then re-use the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to represent the tree as a sequence of bytes in order to write it to a file. That can certainly be done, one example being giving each node a identification number, and representing each node as two such numbers and a symbol.

However you don't need the tree if you construct your [Huffman code canonically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code). The only information you need to send in order to decode canonical Huffman codes is the code *length* (in bits) for each symbol. That is what is normally done.

The list of code lengths can itself be compressed in many ways to reduce the overhead of the code description.